# Vue, How to Normalizing Complex Data and assigning unique Ids

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hey I have been reading articles about normalizing complex data. Currently I have an object that is needing to have new objects generated on button click. I am needing to access the objects by there unique Ids in a component that is also created on that same click. Pictures of the process below. I don't know how to assign new objects to my parent object? as well as normalize my data for having potentially hundreds of unique budget row objects. Any help would be great, I understand the forum posts but don't know how to apply them to my situation

[Vue Forums](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143/2) [Vue Forum Post 2](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/improving-performance-of-deeply-nested-objects-by-normalizing-data/34477)

```
state: {
// Current state of the application lies here.
// budgetRows array at webpage load, base state
budgetRows: {}

},
getters: {
    // Compute derived state based on the current state. More like computed property.
    // Gets budgetRows array from state
    budgetList: state => {
      return state.budgetRows
    },
// should get single array items from budgetRows based on component being accessed
budgetListItem: state => {
  return state.budgetRows
}


},
  mutations: {
    // Mutate the current state
    // Used to create a new row and push into budgetRows array (generate uniq id as well)
    createRow (state) {
      const uid = uniqId()
      Object.assign(state.budgetRows, {[uid]: defaultRow})
      // console.log(state.budgetRows)
    },
```

Child Component:

```
 <div v-for="(budget, index) in budgetRowsList" :key="index">
      {{ index }}
      <budgetItemRowContent></budgetItemRowContent>
      <progress data-min="0" data-max="100" data-value="20"></progress>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="budgetGroupFooter">
  <div class="budgetGroupFooter-Content budgetGroupFooter-Content--Narrow">
    <button class="addBudgetItem" id="addBudgetItem" v-on:click="createNewContent()">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="8" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
        <path fill="#FD0EBF" d="M3 0v3h-3v2h3v3h2v-3h3v-2h-3v-3h-2z"></path>
      </svg>
      Add Item
    </button>
  </div>
</footer>
```

```
<script>
import budgetItemRowContent from '../components/budgetItemRowContent.vue'
import { store } from '../store'

export default {
  name: 'budgetGroup',
  components: {
    budgetItemRowContent,
    store
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      budgetItemHeading: 'Housing'
      // creates array containing object for budget row information
    }
  },
  computed: {
    budgetRowsList () {
      return this.$store.getters.budgetList
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createNewContent () {
      this.$store.commit('createRow')
    }
  }
}
```

[On load of webpage, both label and other input will edit, inputbudget and amountbudgeted respectivly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmET1.png)

[On two clicks, two more child components are created with unique ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhD7W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) is the preferred method of adding new properties to existing object, [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) being another:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// define an initial object state
const defaultRow = {
  inputBudget: '',
  amountBudgeted: 0,
  remaining: 0
}

const state = {
  budgetRows: {}
}

const mutations = {
  createRow (state) {
    const uid = uniqId()

    // with Vue.set
    Vue.set(state.budgetRows, uid, defaultRow)

    // with Object.assign()
    Object.assign(state.budgetRows, { [uid]: defaultRow })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @DigitalDrifter I ended up doing something extremely close to that and yours looks cleaner so I've implemented that style. The issue I'm running into now is that my computed property is not updating when a new row is created.

Updated the code to reflect the challenge.

Comment: I've updated the answer demonstrating another method: `Vue.set`.